# moderncv - how to adjust the personal info

Tags: moderncv

How to adjust my long email address in the personal info in the moderncv?
I use:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm} 
\firstname{Aaaa}
\familyname{bbbb}
\title{ccc}            
\address{ddd. dddddd-4, d.33. dd.145}{dddddd, dddddd}
\mobile{+e~(eee)~555~eeee}
\phone{+f~(fff)~fff~ffff}
\email{johndoeeeeeee@gmail.com}
```

Update: Sorry, my mistake. Now, I have put the full length of the personal info. With this full length my email address is not visible. [image: email address]

Comment: The only problem I can see in your code and the output is that `\address{street and number}{postcode city}` has two obligatory arguments, everything else works fine, including the e-mail address. What is the problem, specifically?

Comment: I have put update to my question

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. With Miktex 2.9 and `moderncv.cls 2012/03/26 v1.0` the email address renders just fine.

Comment: I don't use Miktex I use TexLive. As a beginner I can not comment here, I don't know the differences between them. My address and email all together are too long and email address does not appear next to the phones.

Comment: I can see the problem now, too. Don't have a solution on my hand though. Sasha, it'd be good if you could post a picture of the problematic output.

Comment: @Sasha maybe you have another (older/newer) version? Put `\listfiles` at the very beginning of your `tex`-file and check the log for the version number. I'll test it later on my other machine which runs TeXlive.

Comment: @hakaze I did but nothing changed.

Comment: @Sasha the listfiles it not to change something, but to get your versions of the used packages from your logfile. Post the version of moderncv you see there.

Comment: @JuriRobl Ok, I understand you but I don't understand you. I am beginner in it and I don't know where is what. I know for sure I updated the packages I have... somehow. I am sorry.

Comment: @Sasha OK, on MacTeX 2012 (also TeXlive) I have `moderncv.cls 2012/07/30 v1.1.1`. This version also produces your problem, i.e. the long email address is missing.

Comment: @hakaze: I'm using `moderncv 2012/07/30 v1.1.1` on MiKTeX and I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to a bug which was introduced by recent fixes:

> version 1.1.0 (29 Jul 2012) 
>   ...
>
> - fixed the vertical alignment of the footers, as reported by T. Homa.  Footers are now aligned to the bottom and the letter and cv
>     footers are  perfectly aligned in the "casual" style.

For now you can revert this behavior by adding the following code block in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[c]{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\addtofooter{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\addtofooter{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtofooter{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        %\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}%
        \flushfooter % restores old behavior
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother
```

EDIT: The bug will is fixed in an upcoming update of `moderncv`. Meanwhile use the answer provided by @Xavier which is more advanced than my brute force fix.

Comment: I also informed Xavier Danaux, the package author of `moderncv`, about this problem and our discussion here.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for reporting this bug @hakaze.

The right way to correct the bug is to add

```
\settowidth{\footerboxwidth}{\usebox{\footerbox}}%
```

after line 55 of `moderncvstylecasual.sty`. By forcing `\flushfooter` as suggested above, you will create another regression bug when the footer was normally flushed as part of the regular routine (e.g., if you only want to show your name and address).

I just released a [new version](https://launchpad.net/moderncv/trunk/1.1.2/+download/moderncv-1.1.2.zip) of `moderncv` correcting this bug on [launchpad](http://launchpad.net/moderncv), and will submit it to CTAN once one of the two maintainers is back from holiday.

Comment: Hey Xavier, would you mind adding your name to [this list](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here) for `modenrcv` entry as you wish? (maybe with a link to launchpad with an icon) Glad to have you around here :).